# Simple one: in obj-c, whats the equivalent of C#'s .ToString() method?

Tags: objective-c

Simple one: in obj-c, whats the equivalent of C#'s .ToString() method?

If i have an mystery object of type id, how do i convert it to a string? Is there an easier way than the below?

```
NSString *stringVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mysteryIdObject];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[NSObject description]` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Note that the `%@` string format specifier implicitly calls `-descriptionWithLocale:` if available, or `-description` otherwise.

Comment: @Chris It will, as documented in `NSString` Class Reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific about what you want.  `NSObject` has a `-description` method, which is intended for use when debugging.  Many other classes (like `NSNumber`) respond to `-stringValue`.